# Styling elements inside HTML inside iframe inside a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a complete webpage (html/css/js) wrapped inside iframe within my webpage, this was called by javascript, of course this is from using 3rd party services. is there any way to style the elements inside the html within the iframe? since I dont have control over the webpage it calls, so I cant style them directly from my own webpage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply CSS to iFrame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Answer (score 2):

No. Not possible. You cannot edit html inside an iframe since it is controlled by other domain.